# xcode objective c, EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have this property in my .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSInteger gameMode;
```

And I have this setter in the corresponding .m file:

```
- (void)setGameMode:(NSInteger)mode {
    self.gameMode = mode;
    NSLog(@"game mode %d", self.gameMode);
}
```

In my view controller, I have this function to call the setter when I touch a button:

```
- (IBAction)touchCardButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    if ([self.game disableModeChooseAtFirstTouch]) {
        [self.game setGameMode:self.modeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex];
}
```

But when I click the button in simulator, it will stop here:

```
self.gameMode = mode;
```

And says:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Update:
If I add a NSLog before it, like this:

```
- (void)setGameMode:(NSInteger)mode {
    NSLog(@"game mode %d", self.gameMode);
    self.gameMode = mode;
    NSLog(@"game mode %d", self.gameMode);
}
```

It will keep printing `game mode: 0`

[image: stack trace][image: stack trace]

Can anybody tell me why? Thanks!

Comment: post full error message and stack trace plz

Comment: you need to learn how to debug add a breakpoint for all exception

Comment: You're in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I can tell you why. You are invoking the setter in the setter, causing infinite recursion, stack overflow, and a crash.

Your setGameMode method should read:

```
- (void)setGameMode:(NSInteger)mode 
{
    _gameMode = mode;  //Don't use the setter in the implementation of the setter.
    NSLog(@"game mode %d", self.gameMode);
}
```

Comment: @randomp: Also, if you're not doing anything special in the setter, don't write one. Just use `@property`.

Comment: I see. I'm new to iOS developing. Seems like I need more understanding. Thanks!

Comment: Enrico has a good point. Your current setter doesn't do anything than the compiler-generated synthesizer. Get rid of your custom setter and the problem will go away.